# Ionic: Tabs bar disappears when adding a routerLink

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, navigation

Currently I'm working on an ionic 6 app with angular and a tabs-template. When I try to add a link on an ion-item with routerLink or href, the tab-bar vanishes. I'm pretty new to ionic, so I'd appreciate your help if you know where the problem is!

This is the code I currently use in my one of my page's html:

```
<ion-card>
 <ion-item class="tab1-item" routerLink="/tab2" routerDirection="forward">
  <img src="assets/gif/image.gif">  
 </ion-item>  
</ion-card>
```

I already tried to format it in two other ways with the same outcome:

```
<ion-item class="tab1-item" [routerLink]="/tab2"> 
<ion-item class="tab1-item" href="/tab2">
```

Ionic Info:
       Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.0 (C:\Users\users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
       Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
       @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.7
       @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.7
       @angular/cli                  : 9.1.7
       @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

For reference, this is my tabs-routing-module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'powerChart',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab-power-chart/tab-power-chart.module').then(m => m.TabPowerChartPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },
    ]
  },

{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/powerChart',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

App-routing-module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab-power-chart',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tab-power-chart/tab-power-chart.module').then( m => m.TabPowerChartPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tab1/tab1.module').then( m => m.Tab1PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tab2/tab2.module').then( m => m.Tab2PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tab3/tab3.module').then( m => m.Tab3PageModule)
  }

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And tab1-routing.module.ts, just to make sure:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Tab1Page,

    }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardPageRoutingModule {}
```